# Setup of an archive architecture

Tags: qt, memory-management

My Qt application uses a lot of single windows (`QWidgets` with no parent) on the screen. As the user does not need particular windows any more, for future use he may put them into an archive so they don't appear on the screen any more. If the user opens the archive, in a list that contains the name of the windows, if he clicks on an entry, the window should be reshown.
My question is about the performance: At archive/application start up, should every window be created once and then be hidden, to reshow it at request time, or should every window only exist as a serialized string in an internal list, from which the window is always recreated if requested? Recreating is a bit slower but considering speed of desktop computers I would not mind it. This may be different on handheld devices. Moreover, I am wondering if having thousands of hidden windows (each of them having buttons, sliders, textbrowsers and all that gui stuff) use a lot of memory in Qt.

Reading about [Qt Performance tuning](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt-performance.html), it seems like windows do not seem to take a lot more memory, so I tend to create all of them and only hide them. Is this a good approach?

Comment: Yes it is, but why QWidgets with no parent ?

Comment: I want to move them on the desktop by mouse.

Comment: Firstly, strive for on-demand creation of windows. Secondly, store only information enough to re-create the windows.

Answer (score 0):

Hidden widgets are still listening on events and exist in memory and that implies too many of them cannot be good for the app performance. I would create the common serializeable base for such widgets and stream them to data container e.g. vector (easier on memory) or file (can be flushed to disk) when not in use but expected to restarted. [Serializing](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/datastreamformat.html) Qt types is quite handy.

The blueprint for the architecture you want:

```
class QWidgetS : public QWidget
{
// ...
public:
    template <typename T> static T* showDeserialize(QDataStream& strm)
    {
       T* pWidget = new T();   // create QWidgetS-based object
       pWidget->deserialize(strm); // restore object data
       pWidget->show();        // show the widget
       return pWidget;         // return the pointer to widget
    }

    virtual void serialize(QDataStream& strm);   // need to implement
    virtual void deserialize(QDataStream& strm); // individual child classes
// ...
};

/// sample serialization
void MyWidgetS::serialize(QDataStream& strm)
{
   strm << this->var1 << this->var2;
}

/// sample deserialization
void MyWidgetS::deserialize(QDataStream& strm)
{
   strm >> this->var1 >> this->var2;
}
```